# When to change mode IDE to SATA?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I just received a new Samsung 850 SSD. I checked that disk controller mode should be SATA for better performance but in my case (Windows 7 OS on current old hard disk) it's set to IDE. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Now once I install the new OS (Win 8.1) on this new hard disk - the disk controller mode will still be IDE. So do now I need to go to registry and change the key as mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976) ? After that do I need to change it in BIOS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and change it now.  Change it in the BIOS and registry using the information provided in the MSKB you cited.  And welcome to 2014... IDE for your primary drive is so yesterday. ;)

Once you have done this, upgrading to Win 8.1 should be much smoother for you.  Taking care of this now will eliminate a major variable during the upgrade process.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it in BIOS and then replaced the HD with SSD. But ya the hard disk controller is SATA 2 so drive will run slower. Samsung Magician reported that.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it is correctly set. "AHCI" is the driver used for SATA, and IDE Legacy mode, meant for older OSes is switched off.

You don't need to do anything at all.

As an aside, Samsung has a utility package for their SSDs called magician that will walk you through any changes you need to make to improve performance